# How to get Date from DialogFragment whenever onDateSet method called to container fragment

Tags: android

I want to get date whenever onDataSet called of DialogFragment to container fragment which name is FromToDateFragment.java. The code of 
**FromDatePicker.java:**

```
String keyDate;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    keyDate = String.valueOf(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/").append(month+1).append("/").append(year));

}
}
```

In above class the onDateSet method called and set value of keyDate variable whenever date set by user. Now i want to get this date to container fragment which name is FromToDateFragment.java.

FromToDateFragment.java

```
public class FromToDateFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    String keyFromDate, keyToDate = null;
//    getFromToDateFromFromToDateFragment getDate;
    SessionManager sessionManager;
    TextView fromDateTextView;
    TextView toDateTextView;
    String fromDate, toDate;



@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.from_to_date_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.from_date:
                DialogFragment from = new FromDatePicker();
                from.show(manager, "fromDatePicker");
                break;
            case R.id.to_date:
                DialogFragment to = new ToDatePicker();
                to.show(manager, "toDatePicker");
                break;
        }
    }
```

In this fragment, i just show this diaglogFragment by this code

```
DialogFragment from = new FromDatePicker();
                from.show(manager, "fromDatePicker");
```

when click on a button. Kindly tell me how i can get date in FromToDateFragment.java class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in an implementation of the `OnDateSetListener` to the fragments `FromDatePicker` and `ToDatePicker` through a setter instead of having them implement it themselves